# Binding doesn't seem to update after startup

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a textbox in my View which is not getting the binding properly:

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding Game.Players[0].PlayerDeck.PlayerCardInDeckCount, StringFormat=Deck ({0})}" />`

On startup it shows the correct value stored in `PlayerCardInDeckCount`. But when I "draw" a card, it shows the card drawn in the "hand" (so this binding works ! yeah !) but it doesn't seems to trigger the propertychanged thing while I am sure the `PlayerCardInDeckCount` did change.

The draw a card occurs when I click on a button. this is the code in ViewModel for the button

```
public void DrawCard()
{
    Game.MoveCard(Game.Players[Game.ActivePlayer - 1].PlayerDeck.PlayerCardInDeck, Game.Players[Game.ActivePlayer - 1].PlayerDeck.PlayerCardInHand);
}
```

the method

```
public void MoveCard(BindingList<PlayerCardModel> from, BindingList<PlayerCardModel> destination, int index = -1, int quantity = 1)
        {
            if (index == -1)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= quantity; i++)
                {
                    PlayerCardModel card;
                    card = from.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (card != null)
                    {
                        destination.Add(card);
                        from.Remove(card);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageLog += DateTime.Now + " - Système - Le deck est vide !\n";
                        i = quantity;
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

Why does the movement from a list to another works, but not the count update?

Comment: `PropertyChanged` isn't triggered while adding/removing items from a BindingList. Use the `BindingList<T>.ListChanged` instead. You could use a `ItemsControl` to bind your BindingList to generate multiple cards? _(I've never worked with a BindingList, I always go for the `ObservableCollection<T>`)_

Comment: You need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the data-bound `PlayerCardInDeckCount` property. Moving an item in `Game` does not.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I like the idea of itemscontrol to generate multiple cards, that's what I used for the "hand" side of things but didn't think of it for the deck" side... will try that. 
I will look into listchanged too ! 
Concerning the need to raise the PropertyChanged event, I, for the moment, don't know how to raise the event of a sub-sub-property in the game object :-(

Comment: Your TextBox binds to: "Game.Players[**0**].PlayerDeck.PlayerCardInDeckCount"
But MoveCard operates on "Game.Players[**Game.ActivePlayer - 1**].PlayerDeck.PlayerCardInDeck"
This will be the same player only if Game.ActivePlayer has a value of 1.

Also to my opinion you should bind to `PlayerCardInDeck.Count` rather than to `PlayerCardInDeckCount`. I guess the count change of a binding list raises an event that WPF ItemsControl notice  - though its not INotifyPropertyChanged - but BindingList is supported by WPF standard controls.